# Selecting data based on multiple fields (Where And)

Tags: sql, forms, vba, select

I have large amounts of data that I am trying to sort out based on two cascading combo boxes. I get error `Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression` and it points me to:

```
ElseIf [Forms]![Send To GE]![cboFil] = "LCP" Then
strSQL = "Select * From [To_GE] Where [Community] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboSubFil.Value & Chr(34) And [LCP] = "& Chr(34) & Me.cboSSubFil.Value & Chr(34)"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

It seems that the `And` should work for this. What's causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strSQL = "Select * From [To_GE] Where [Community] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboSubFil.Value &     Chr(34) And [LCP] = "& Chr(34) & Me.cboSSubFil.Value & Chr(34)"
```

Should maybe be

```
strSQL = "Select * From [To_GE] Where [Community] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboSubFil.Value & Chr(34) & " And [LCP] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboSSubFil.Value & Chr(34)
```

To make things read a little easier though I would recommend escaping your quotes or switching to single quotes in the query

```
strSQL = "Select * From [To_GE] Where [Community] = '" & Me.cboSubFil.Value & "' And [LCP] = '" & Me.cboSSubFil.Value & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me past that error! Now I can't get past the next line "Data mis-match" in the criteria. It seems that its a common problem especially with dates, but all of my fields are text.

All of my other Select statements are working, its just this one with the multiple "Where" that is hanging me up!

Comment: If it makes a difference [LCP] is a list of numbers 1-35, but the field is a text field.

Comment: If the field is a date in access then you must wrap it around a hashtag "#" if it is a number then don't wrap it with anything.  So for it date the query should render like this : myDate=#1/1/1900# for a number field it must be myNumber=1

Comment: The Field is not a date. The Field is Text but contains a number 1-35. So the number should be stored as text. I played with this all weekend with no real progress. I read somewhere that I could make a temp table and select from it or a query? I didn't entirely follow.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query in Access with hard coded values?  The query seems pretty basic and doesn't seem to need a temp table to query against.  The error Data mis-match, means that one of the fields you're querying doesn't match the type of the expression.  I just noticed something in the query both [community] and [lcp] are based on cboSubFil.Value, should one of these values be different?

Comment: Thanks everybody, you all helped me get past my hiccup. After staring for so long I had gone blind and didn't see my "''" error or my field/form data mismatch!